# can't get reference with include tag

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have developed a app. In my app there are:
Product.java (fragment)
product.xml (contain a listview and a include tag)
list_single(row of listview)

This is my code:

Product.java

```
public class Product extends Fragment{

    public int ITEM_SELECTED = 1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> PROD;

    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product, container, false);

        String [] ELEMENTS1 = {
            "A","b","c"};

        ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        TextView a = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageButton add_cart = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        switch(ITEM_SELECTED){

            case 1: PROD = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.single_row, R.id.textView, ELEMENTS1);break;

        }
        listView.setAdapter(PROD);

        add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("asd","asd");
           }
        });
        return v;
    }

}
```

product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/layout">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="PRODOTTI"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <include layout="@layout/single_row"
        android:id="@+id/ly"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is list_single.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2" />

<ImageButton
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:src="@drawable/product"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Q.TA"
    android:textColor="#083CBF"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PREZZO"
    android:textColor="#083CBF"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="COLLI"
    android:textColor="#083CBF"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:id="@+id/ded"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Problem:
When i try to click on `imagebutton` it doesn't show Log.d. It seems that
`OnClickListener` is not run. I have tried: `setText("xy");` but that doesn't work either.

Is the problem is in listview?
I can't use the elements of single_row. My app doesn't crash. Please, help! Thank you

UPDATE:

```
listView.setAdapter(PROD);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            ImageButton add_cart = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

            add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("asd", "asd");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hi",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

```
ImageButton add_cart = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Your imagebutton `button2` is in `list_single.xml` and you are trying to find it in  View inflated using `product.xml`. And that too before you are setting the adapter for the ListView. So at the point where you are getting reference to your ImageButton there is view rendering for the ListView. Here is what you should ideally do

```
listView.setAdapter(PROD);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    ImageButton add_cart = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
     //more logic
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me.. i have updated 1st post.. When i Click on add_cart button.. in log there is D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN